# Is it possible to filter by Content Type Variant in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have 3 Variants of a Content Type. On one Variant I am listing nodes of that Content Type with a View. I'd like to control what the View returns by limiting the results to 1 variant of the content type.

I've looked through the filter options but haven't found anything that works. Would anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Are you talking about Panels variants? Just create different views for each panel.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Niall comment, if is only one contentype, use only one variant and control what to display in views, use content panes views, set contextual filters, relations, and how to pass parameters between views and panels in views ui middle column, pane views are design to "talk" with panels, make several views as needed, add them all to panel variant, and control wich pane to display in panel rules settings.
If there are more than one contentype, add a variant for each one.